# CakePHP Invoicing App & Deleting Data From Another Controller/Model

Tags: mysql, database, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm new to CakePHP and I could do with some newbie advice please.

I'm creating an invoicing application and the way I have it set up is with seperate tables (and so Models and Controlllers) for Invoices and Items. The Invoice table holds the data such as 'Invoice Number', 'Date' and  'Client ID' for example, and the Items table stores individual records/items that make up each invoice with 'Quantity', 'Unit Price' etc. The two are associated correctly.

When I call the 'edit' view for Invoices, obviously passing an ID, I retrieve the record and then also loop through the all associated records returned from the Items table to - all works as planned and are retrieved and displayed correctly.

What I want to be able to do from this view though, is to be able to delete individual items from the invoice by clicking on a delete button next to each - ideally with a confirmation box. How would this be acheived exactly? What would be the best method? Would I use a function in the Items controller to do this without leaving the page? How would I call the function in that controller from the Invoice controller/view? Or would another method such as the CakePHP query() function be used for this?

I hope I've explained this setup clearly enough for someone to offer any help and/or advice for which I would be very thankful.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The simple way:

In your Invoice/view.ctp 
Inside your foreach loop you would do something like this:

```
//this is loose code since you have not pasted any in your question

    <?php echo $this->Html->link('Delete', array('controller'=>'Item', 'action'=>'delete', $item['Item']['id'])); ?>
```

then create the function in your ItemController.php

```
function delete($id=NULL){
if($id){
   $this->Item->delete($id);
   $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invoice item deleted', true));
   $this->redirect($this->referer());
}
}
```

Comment: Ahh, makes perfect sense and I shall give that a try. Thanks for the example code too when I'm back at my system. A happy New Year to you sir.

Comment: One other thought though...is this method safe to implement as I'm not specifically sending it as a POST request? Could a direct call to the URL therefore be used to delete an item (i.e. ..item/delete/1 etc)?

Comment: Yes, you are correct on the url parameters being able to delete a guess of the id. Permissions will have a large part in this technique, only allowing users to delete their own Invoice Items. You could do it as a post but there is easily a hack for that as well.